# Can I include additional columns in the export that are not visible in the SSRS report viewer?

Tags: reporting-services

The additional columns are included in the dataset query, but not added to the table.  Does anyone know if it is possible to display additional columns in the export that are not visible in the SSRS report viewer?

Answer (score 4):

The export mechanisms is built to export only visible fields (objects). 
Meaning what you see on the report viewer is what you will get when exported.

However, there is a way to workaround it.

I assume you configured the visibility of the fields.

You can use this global variable `=Globals!RenderFormat.Name` to control the visibility of the fields, when exported to a specific supported format

For example if the Render format is Excel you will show the field otherwise it will be hidden.

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", False, True)
```

[More Details about Render format](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx)

Comment: +1 for your idea. Additionally I checked, that for SSRS versions, that export report to XLSX format, you need to modify the expression a little bit. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334886/hide-column-in-ssrs

Comment: You can also check `Globals!IsInteractive` - This will be `False` for any export format